# Php Image Download Link not Working

Tags: php, image

I already try to download image using below code but it work in localhost in my computer but when site live on hosting service then when i click download link the show a message
**Headers Sent**

not download image.Please give me solve.

**link use:**

```
print'<p><a href="?u=download&file=nplace_image/'. $rs[$i][16].'" class="btn"><i class="icon-cloud-download"></i> Download</a></p>';
```

**my code:**

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'];

download_file($file);

function download_file( $fullPath ){

  // Must be fresh start
  if( headers_sent() )
    die('Headers Sent');

  // Required for some browsers
  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

  // File Exists?
  if( file_exists($fullPath) ){

    // Parse Info / Get Extension
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    // Determine Content Type
    switch ($ext) {
      case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
      case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
      case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
      case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
      case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
      case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
      case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
      case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
      case "jpeg":
      case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
      default: $ctype="application/force-download";
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $fullPath );

  } else
    die('File Not Found');

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is output before executing your download code. So it shows this message. You can check if your server logs anything in error log file. Also you can try a ob_clean before calling the download_file function.

Comment: i use ob_clean(); but same problem

Comment: Please add ob_clean() before calling function download_file($file);

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['file'])) {
    $file = isset($_GET['file'])?$_GET['file']:'';

    download_file($file);
    }

    function download_file( $fullPath ){

      // Must be fresh start
      if( headers_sent() )
        die('Headers Sent');

      // Required for some browsers
      if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

      // File Exists?
      if( file_exists($fullPath) ){

        // Parse Info / Get Extension
        $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
        $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

        // Determine Content Type
        switch ($ext) {
          case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
          case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
          case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
          case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
          case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
          case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
          case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
          case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
          case "jpeg":
          case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
          default: $ctype="application/force-download";
        }

        header("Pragma: public"); // required
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
        header("Content-Type: $ctype");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile( $fullPath );

} else
    die('File Not Found');

}
?>

    <?php print'<p><a href="?u=download&file=noteII007.jpg" class="btn"><i class="icon-cloud-   download"></i> Download</a></p>';?>
```